# black screen on simulator SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var horizontalLines: [CGFloat] = [50, 100]
@State private var verticalLines: [CGFloat] = [100, 200]
@GestureState private var dragOffset: CGSize = CGSize.zero

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                .border(Color.black, width: 1)
            
            ForEach(horizontalLines, id: \.self) { y in
                LineView(startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y), endPoint: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width, y: y))
                    .gesture(horizontalDragGesture(y: y))
            }
            
            ForEach(verticalLines, id: \.self) { x in
                LineView(startPoint: CGPoint(x: x, y: 0), endPoint: CGPoint(x: x, y: geometry.size.height))
                    .gesture(verticalDragGesture(x: x))
            }
        }
        .background(Color.white)
        .gesture(containerDragGesture(geometry: geometry))
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}

private func horizontalDragGesture(y: CGFloat) -> some Gesture {
    DragGesture()
        .updating($dragOffset) { value, state, _ in
            state = value.translation
        }
        .onChanged { value in
            let newY = y + value.translation.height
            guard let index = horizontalLines.firstIndex(of: y) else { return }
            horizontalLines[index] = newY
        }
}

private func verticalDragGesture(x: CGFloat) -> some Gesture {
    DragGesture()
        .updating($dragOffset) { value, state, _ in
            state = value.translation
        }
        .onChanged { value in
            let newX = x + value.translation.width
            guard let index = verticalLines.firstIndex(of: x) else { return }
            verticalLines[index] = newX
        }
}

private func containerDragGesture(geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some Gesture {
    DragGesture()
        .updating($dragOffset) { value, state, _ in
            state = value.translation
        }
        .onEnded { value in
            let offsetX = value.translation.width
            let offsetY = value.translation.height
            let containerRightBorder = geometry.size.width + offsetX
            let containerBottomBorder = geometry.size.height + offsetY
            
            if let rightMostLineX = verticalLines.last, containerRightBorder < rightMostLineX {
                verticalLines[verticalLines.count - 1] = containerRightBorder
            }
            
            if let bottomMostLineY = horizontalLines.last, containerBottomBorder < bottomMostLineY {
                horizontalLines[horizontalLines.count - 1] = containerBottomBorder
            }
        }
}

struct LineView: View {
    var startPoint: CGPoint
    var endPoint: CGPoint
    
    var body: some View {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: startPoint)
            path.addLine(to: endPoint)
        }
        .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2)
      }
    }
  }

  struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
   }
 }
```

This code gives me a black screen in both the preview and simulator and I don't understand what can be wrong it gives no errors. This is supposed to be a container with interactive inner lines. The output looks like this:

[image]

I want to understand maybe I messed up the output part, I am very new to Swift and would appreciate the help

Comment: you need to apply background color for Rectangle by default it will take black color for built-in shapes`GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red) ------> add this line and check
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                .border(Color.black, width: 1)` and then play around with your code for required output

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the points in LineView. It seems that the start and end points of each line are set outside the range of the GeometryReader, which is causing the lines not to be visible.

To fix this, you'll need to scale the points by the size of the GeometryReader.

Replace  -

```
ForEach(horizontalLines, id: \.self) { y in
  LineView(startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y), endPoint: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width, y: y))
    .gesture(horizontalDragGesture(y: y))
}
```

with -

```
ForEach(horizontalLines, id: \.self) { y in
  LineView(startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y * geometry.size.height / 100), 
         endPoint: CGPoint(x: geometry.size.width, y: y * geometry.size.height / 100))
    .gesture(horizontalDragGesture(y: y)) 
}
```

AND

Replace -

```
ForEach(verticalLines, id: \.self) { x in
  LineView(startPoint: CGPoint(x: x, y: 0), endPoint: CGPoint(x: x, y: geometry.size.height))
    .gesture(verticalDragGesture(x: x))
}
```

With -

```
ForEach(verticalLines, id: \.self) { x in
  LineView(startPoint: CGPoint(x: x * geometry.size.width / 100, y: 0), 
         endPoint: CGPoint(x: x * geometry.size.width / 100, y: geometry.size.height))
    .gesture(verticalDragGesture(x: x))
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it still gives me black screen

Comment: Have you tried to clean the build folder (In Xcode, Product -> Clean Build Folder)?

Comment: Just did that still just gives me a black screen I wrote the algorithm in Flutter and now I try to convert it to swift

Comment: 1. First, confirm whether your LineView is working as expected. You could test this by creating a LineView with static start and end points in a new SwiftUI View.

Comment: 2. If LineView works as expected, then test if your GeometryReader and ZStack are working correctly.

Comment: 3. If the above two steps worked as expected, then the problem might be in the ForEach loops or gestures. You might want to test your code by commenting out the gestures and see if it makes any difference.